# echo "-e" doesn't print anything

Tags: bash

I'm using GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). And this command:

```
echo "-e"
```

doesn't print anything. I guess this is because "-e" is one of a valid options of echo command because echo "-n" and echo "-E" (the other two options) also produce empty strings.

The question is how to escape the sequence "-e" for echo to get the natural output ("-e").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a tough one ;)

Usually you would use double dashes to tell the command that it should stop interpreting options, but echo will only output those:

```
$ echo -- -e
-- -e
```

You can use -e itself to get around the problem:

```
$ echo -e '\055e'
-e
```

Also, as others have pointed out, if you don't insist on using the bash builtin `echo`, your `/bin/echo` binary might be the GNU version of the tool (check the man page) and thus understand the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e
-e
```

Comment: Do you happen to know, why `echo -e` does not work from Makefiles?

Comment: @dma_k: works for me(tm). make(1) does not use the $SHELL builtin you are using, so it will behave differently.

Comment: Thanks, great! Indeed, setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` in Makefile solved the problem!

Comment: What about `/bin/echo -n`? POSIXLY_CORECT=1 won't work for it :(

Comment: @Radu: the other workaround is still available to you

Answer (score 15):

The one true way to print any arbitrary string:

```
printf "%s" "$vars"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice? But this won't work for embedded ANSI Escape sequences, and depends on who the value was assigned.  Try `v="$(tput sgr0)"; printf "%s" "$v"` or `v=$(printf '\033[4m'); printf "%s" "$v"`etc.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler, if you want `%b` rather than `%s`... well, it's available in all POSIX printf implementations, and that gives you the same escape-sequence handling as found in `echo`.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way, but this works:

```
printf -- "-e\n"
```

Comment: In this case it works but it doesn't solve the global problem. Consider: printf "--version"

Comment: @wheleph You have ignored the "--" before the "-e\n". This separates options from arguments. This is the best, portable (across shells) answer. +1.

Comment: I agree that `printf` is the best, portable answer -- but disagree (strongly!) that embedding data in the format string is the right way to teach its use; that way lies people writing `printf -- "$var\n"` when they should be using `printf '%s\n' "$var"`, and that way lies format string injections (which, while not necessarily security-impacting in bash, can certainly lead to annoying bugs).

Answer (score 4):

You could cheat by doing

```
echo "-e "
```

That would be dash, e, space.

Alternatively you can use the more complex, but more precise:

```
echo -e \\\\x2De
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 
[root@scintia mail]# POSIXLY_CORRECT=1; export POSIXLY_CORRECT
[root@scintia mail]# /bin/echo "-e"
-e
[root@scintia mail]#
```

Comment: Just 'POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e' (without the 's) is enough. Although this is not using the BASH version of echo

Comment: Information about Bash POSIX mode: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/BashPOSIXMode.html. Item 41 addresses echo command. The only question left for me is why 
[root@scintia mail]# POSIXLY_CORRECT=1; export POSIXLY_CORRECT; echo "-e"; 
doesn't work

Comment: Vinko, '/bin/echo -e' is also enough:)

Answer (score 1):

After paying careful attention to the man page :)

```
SYSV3=1 /usr/bin/echo -e
```

works, on Solaris at least

Comment: I haven't found any references to SYSV3 env variable in Linux echo man page

Comment: Looks like the POSIXLY_CORRECT env var from another answer is the equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
echo x-e | sed 's/^x//'
```

This is the way recommended by the [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html):

> [...] It is often possible to avoid this problem using 'echo "x$word"', taking the 'x' into account later in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I like that one using a herestring:

```
cat <<<"-e"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
echo -e' '
echo -e " \b-e"
```

Comment: tho it outputs more than just "-e" under the hood :)

Answer (score -2):

```
/bin/echo -e
```

works, but why?

```
[resin@nevada ~]$ which echo 
/bin/echo
```

Comment: If you write "echo -e" it uses the bash internal echo, and writing "/bin/echo -e" uses the external /bin/echo command. 
But on my Ubuntu 8.04 box none of the two versions work..

Comment: `which` will tell you which binary will be used, but it won't tell if your shell has a built-in function of the same name (which would probably be used instead of the binary). You can use `type` instead of `which` to find out more information.