# echo "-n" will not print -n?

Tags: bash, echo

Very similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320313/echo-e-doesnt-print-anything).

I'm iterating through a few things with an automated script in BASH. Occasionally the script will come across "-n" and echo will attempt to interpret this.

Attempted this:

```
 $ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -n
```

and

```
 $ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo "-n"
```

But it interpreted the argument each time.

Then this, which works but it's possible to hit escaped characters in the strings, which is why I don't want to apply a null character to all input and use -e.

```
$ echo -e "\x00-n"
-n
```

printf is possible, but is to be avoided unless there are no other options (Not all machines have printf as a utility).

```
$ printf "%s" "-n"
-n
```

So is there a way to get echo to print "-n"?

Comment: Tangentially related, http://everything2.com/title/The+UNIX+and+the+Echo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printf` should be a built-in in all your shells, unless some of your machines have very old shell versions. It's been a built-in in `bash` for a long time. It's probably more portable than `echo -e`.

Otherwise, there's really no way to get `echo` options it cares about.

**Edit**: from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042734/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-bash-strange-behavior/13042777#13042777) to another similar question; avoid quoting issues with `printf` by using this handy no-digital-rights-retained wrapper:

```
ech-o() { printf "%s\n" "$*"; }
```

(That's ech-o, as in "without options")

Comment: printf is way more portable than echo, but be sure to pass the string you want to print as an argument, *not* as a format string (i.e. `printf "%s\n" "$stringtoprint"` instead of `printf "$stringtoprint\n"`) -- see @djhaskin987's answer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I egotistically added a note from a different answer of mine, which I think is a nice solution.

Comment: Hah! +1 for an actual appropriate use of `"$*"`

Comment: Note that `printf` is not built-in in pdksh and many of its modern derivatives like `mksh`.

Comment: Note that in POSIX shells, the expansion of `$*` is dependant on `$IFS`. Use `echo() (IFS=' '; printf '%s\n' "$*")` to make sure the arguments are joined with spaces even in contexts where `$IFS` may have been modified.

Comment: Also note that several shells (`ksh93`, `dash`, `yash` at least) won't accept `ech-o` as a function name.

Answer (score 4):

What about prefixing the string with a character ("x" for instance) that gets removed on-the-fly with a cut:

```
echo "x-n" | cut -c 2-
```

Answer (score 4):

echo "-n" tells the shell to put '-n' as echo's first argument, character for character. Semantically, `echo "-n"` is the same as `echo -n`. Try this instead (it's a POSIX standard and should work on any shell):

```
printf '%s\n' "-n"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you invoke Bash with the name `sh`, it will mimic *sh*, where the `-n` option was not available to `echo`. I'm not sure if that fits your needs though.

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo -n'
```

Comment: That `-n` is unspecified in the POSIX.2 shell command specification is flatly untrue. Option (non-string) behavior for `-n` is specified as part of the baseline (non-XSI) standard behavior for `echo`; it's only shells implementing the optional XSI extensions where it isn't present. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- now, granted, _your_ `/bin/sh` may follow XSI, but that's not universally guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "-n"` will not print `-n` because `-n` is interpreted as an option for `echo` (see `help echo`). But you can use:

```
echo -e "\055n"
```

Comment: This is supported with GNU's implementation of `echo`, but not with any POSIX-compliant version -- an XSI-compliant POSIX implementation of `echo` would print the literal `-e`, and a non-XSI one wouldn't interpret the `\055`. Indeed, if you `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` on a GNU system, you'll see the former behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Cheating method:

```
echo -e  "\r-n"
```

Comment: ...which works if your output is for human consumption, but not if it's to be read by a program or other non-terminal consumer.