# Echoing an echo argument in Bash

Tags: string, bash, unix, echo, bash4

Here is the code that shows the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

function char() {
    local char="$(echo $1 | cut -c2)"    # Gets second character from argument.
    echo $char
}

char -a                                  # Outputs 'a'.
char -e                                  # Or 'char -n' outputs nothing.
```

I want this code to output [ 'a', 'e' ] instead of [ 'a', nothing ].

I think that the problem is in *echo $1*. My question is kind of similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320313/echo-e-doesnt-print-anything). But it seems that most solutions don't work for me. I think that Bash changed it's behavior from version in that question: '3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)'.

My Bash version is '4.3.30(1)-release (i586-pc-linux-gnu)'. I have tried:

```
echo x-e                                 # Outputs 'x-e'.
echo -- -e                               # Outputs '-- -e'.
echo "-e "                               # Outputs '-e'.
```

Only little "hack" that works is *echo "$1 "*. But I've got the feeling that it's not the best thing to do.

P.S.
I personally find this pretty interesting. Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-e` is a flag some versions of `echo` interpret.  The solution here is don't use `echo`, instead use `printf`:

```
printf '%s' "$1" | cut -c2
```

From `help echo` in bash:

> ```
> Options:
>  -n        do not append a newline
>  -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
>  -E        explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

so when the variable expands and you try to run `echo -e` it's not going to echo the string `-e` it's telling `echo` to make backslashes mean the escape sequence.

For a thorough discussion of [Why printf is better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) read the excellent answers there.

If you're trying to process command line options here, you might consider other approaches though.  Like [getopts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) or reading [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) about some great options

Comment: Also, in this particular case, you can use a substring expansion to get the second character instead of using `cut`: `printf '%s' "${1:1:1}"` (The three "1"s mean, the first parameter, starting at character #1 (#0 is the first character), return just one character.) Dependong in how this'll be used, you might also want to use `printf '%s\n'` to add a newline to the output.

Comment: The question wasn't about using `printf` instead of `echo`. But anyway your answer is the only one.

Comment: @GordonDavisson , you don't even need to use printf in your case, `local char=${1:1:1}` is enough.

Comment: Also, when its needed to pipe some variable's content to a command I would suggest to use ["here string"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) like that: `local char=$(cut -c2 <<< "$1")` instead of echo or printf.

Comment: @YooryN. Good point; doing a direct assignment (without the `$( )` stuff) simplifies it even further.